# Python == many statements instead of if/elif

Tags: python

I am trying this below.

```
my_list = []

for row in reader: 
    a = row[0]
    b = row[1]
    c = row[2]
    s=("{0:<5s} {1:<5s} {2:<8s} ".format(a,b,c))
    lst = my_list.append(s)
    if b == ("Home"):
        n_lst = new_lst.appen(s)
```

I want if row b in my output equals "home" "gone" etc to put that line in a new list. I tried

```
if b == ("home", "gone"):
```

but that doesn't work, is there a way to keep adding things to my if == statement instead of doing a bunch of elif statements?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `in` keyword instead:

```
if b in ['home', 'gone']:
```

This checks to see if `b` is an element of that list.

Also, you seem to have a spelling mistake here:

```
n_lst = new_lst.appen(s)
                     ^
```

Comment: @defuz: Why? If you're optimizing for performance, wouldn't a `set`/`frozenset` be better?

Comment: @Blender, because `tuple` is immutable. Set in this case is not necessary, since the comparison is only 1 time.

Comment: @defuz: It really makes no difference. `set` will always be faster, so you can use either tuples or lists if you aren't optimizing the code. I'm just used to lists.

Comment: @Blender, `set` will be 2 times slower in this case. Check it.)

Comment: @Blender, I just used to enjoy `tuple` whenever I do not need to change it. Almost no difference really, do not pay attention.

Comment: @Blender and Ashwini Chaudhary: Actually, testing for membership in a set literal is slower than testing for membership in a tuple literal because of the time it takes to create the literal.  Try it with `timeit`.  It's surprising, but true.  When creation of the literal is moved outside of the loop, creation time is amortized and the expected speedup of using a set occurs.  If you cannot move set creation out of the loop prefer `if something in (item, item2, item3)` over `if something in {item, item2, item3}`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: My bad, I thought that @defuz was talking about `if something in container`, where `container` is a `set`, `tuple` or `list`. Creating the container each time you loop will definitely slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to keep adding things to my if == statement

An or?

```
if b == "home" or b == "gone":
```